# How to align caption and table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

This is what I have:

[image]

and what I need is the table's caption aligned to the left of the table (which is centered). Like this:

[image]

The answer I'm looking for must contain the table centered. This is some of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[top = 2cm, bottom = 1.5cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} %  \toprule y \bottomrule
\usepackage[scr = rsfso]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont = bf, justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false, format = hang}
    \captionsetup[sub]{labelfont = up, justification = centering}
\usepackage{subcaption} 



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H] \centering
    \caption{Term\'ometros usuales.}
    \begin{tabular}{llc} \toprule
        Term\'ometro & Propiedad Termom\'etrica & Notaci\'on \\ \hline
        Gas (volumen constante) & Presi\'on & $p$ \\
        Resistencia de platino (tensi\'on constante) & Resistencia El\'ectrica & $R'$ \\
        Termopar (tensi\'on constante) & Fem t\'ermica & $E$ \\
        Vapor de helio (saturado) & Presi\'on & $p$ \\
        Sal paramagn\'etica & Susceptibilidad magn\'etica & $\chi$ \\
        Radiaci\'on de cuerpo negro & Emitancia radiante & $R_{b, \lambda}$ \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{CyT:tempGases:tiposTermometros}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your MWE does not produce the output you show --- there are packages missing (at least, something to enable the `H` option to `table`).

Comment: Sorry. Now should work

Comment: You should have a geometry also, the table doesn't fit otherwise. Anyway, try to change the tabular with `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{llc}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) To align the caption with the tabular add the package `threeparttable` and put the caption inside the `threeparttable` enviroment.

(2) The table does not fit in the line width. One option (there are several) it to reduce the width of the first column by defining a new column type.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs} %  \toprule y \bottomrule
\usepackage[scr = rsfso]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont = bf, justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false, format = hang}

\captionsetup[sub]{labelfont = up, justification = centering}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

%\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,showframe]{geometry}% added for larger margins


\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % added

\usepackage{array} % added <<<<<<<<<
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[H] \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Term\'ometros usuales.}    
        \begin{tabular}{L{0.4\linewidth}lc}% changed <<<<<<<<<<
             \toprule
            Term\'ometro & Propiedad Termom\'etrica & Notaci\'on \\ \hline
            Gas (volumen constante) & Presi\'on & $p$ \\
            Resistencia de platino (tensi\'on constante) & Resistencia El\'ectrica & $R'$ \\
            Termopar (tensi\'on constante) & Fem t\'ermica & $E$ \\
            Vapor de helio (saturado) & Presi\'on & $p$ \\
            Sal paramagn\'etica & Susceptibilidad magn\'etica & $\chi$ \\
            Radiaci\'on de cuerpo negro & Emitancia radiante & $R_{b, \lambda}$ \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{CyT:tempGases:tiposTermometros}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Setting the width of the first column to `0.4\linewidth` seems a bit *ad hoc*. How did you arrive at this particular value? Can you think of a way to automate the column width choice?

Comment: @ Mico The OP just wanted to align the caption with the top line.
There are many ways to make the tabular  (perhaps dummy for this MWE) fit the line : change the font size, use another package, and `\\\`  inside the wider cell... With 0.4\linewidth  only one cell is modified.

Answer (score 3):

Your code contains a bigger problem than the start of the caption string not being aligned with the left-hand edge of the tabular material. This bigger problem is that the code provides no guarantee that the tabular material will actually fit inside the width of the text block. Indeed, for the minimal example you posted, the tabular material exceeds the width of the textblock (given by the parameter `\textwidth`) noticeably.

To fix this bigger problem, I suggest you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment, set its overall width to `\textwidth`, and employ the `X` column type for the first column. That way, LaTeX automates the process of choosing a suitable width for the first column. (Actually, in the code below, I use a modified version of the `X` column type which also performs hanging indentation automatically.)

As a happy side effect of this change, you no longer need to do anything special to align the start of the caption and the left-hand edge of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{tabularx} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}X}

\usepackage{booktabs} %  \toprule y \bottomrule
\usepackage[scr = rsfso]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont = bf, 
                  justification = raggedright, 
                  singlelinecheck = false, 
                  format = hang,
                  skip=0.333\baselineskip} % <-- new option
    \captionsetup[sub]{labelfont = up, 
                  justification = centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] 
%%\centering % no longer needed
\caption{Term\'ometros usuales.}
\label{CyT:tempGases:tiposTermometros}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} Llc @{}} 
    \toprule
    Term\'ometro & Propiedad Termom\'etrica & Notaci\'on \\ 
    \midrule % why use "\hline"??
    Gas (volumen constante) & Presi\'on & $p$ \\
    Resistencia de platino (tensi\'on constante) & Resistencia el\'ectrica & $R'$ \\
    Termopar (tensi\'on constante) & Fem t\'ermica & $E$ \\
    Vapor de helio (saturado) & Presi\'on & $p$ \\
    Sal paramagn\'etica & Susceptibilidad magn\'etica & $\chi$ \\
    Radiaci\'on de cuerpo negro & Emitancia radiante & $R_{b, \lambda}$ \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful ! The first column will always use the textwidth that's left from others columns? Do I explain my self?

Comment: @Peluche - That’s correct: The width of the first column is determined as a residual or “left over”, as you put it.